# JSON loads returning unicode instead of dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode

So I have a JSON object like the one below. I'm trying to turn it into a dictionary, but when I try `json.loads(data)`, it returns a list of unicode strings. How do I get it to return as a dictionary instead?

```
["{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6016055eae4d3e3f89d243719a272f\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30264, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d6016055eae4d3e3f89d243719a272f\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30264, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d601605a7e5cc16f5531e4efdabee0c\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d604702b7b3609fad5b7b4f63bef631\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30265, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 0, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 0, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": []}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6088b7f83e1744f17f7e4d30bb76c9\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30266, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d6088b7f83e1744f17f7e4d30bb76c9\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30266, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d6088b801f1fd4b306a9f4266b3a858\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d609444b830ade0b13e7b419eb8af2e\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30267, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d609444b830ade0b13e7b419eb8af2e\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30267, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d609444f48dbdde72c9864ec99ea271\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d60b578c55ae362f6421c405ab5e542\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30268, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d60b578c55ae362f6421c405ab5e542\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30268, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d60b578e608a00d44b2a340c7b468d5\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6106d8907ebd35b49d8e4fdc8ef0e6\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30269, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 0, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 0, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": []}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6124b3097faaf9f18e1b4dc7bd7208\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30270, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d6124b3097faaf9f18e1b4dc7bd7208\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30270, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d6124b3291c90d33d6a1245e586325b\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61689633572e1962fe3d46aeb94328\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30271, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 9900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 9900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 1000, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61689633572e1962fe3d46aeb94328\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30271, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d6168963e7816da25f7a4437db1e632\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d617924f367cf778c4d734baebf25ab\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30272, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d617924f367cf778c4d734baebf25ab\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30272, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d617924fd3674899f54f04e7c9d0ab6\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61846d719a2ec1b6dbe14806a3141d\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30273, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61846d719a2ec1b6dbe14806a3141d\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30273, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61846d7aca9ba148d09f422aba4a0a\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61994886375b4f8360784dc3ac025c\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30274, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61994886375b4f8360784dc3ac025c\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30274, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d619948a056ccfa6f19ca4a019a80d3\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61b7ee74e6c50b05f20342f0a5fe12\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30275, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 500, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61b7ee74e6c50b05f20342f0a5fe12\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30275, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61b7ee7efaaa2af9f4be4458a6fc49\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61d2b1df01d7d28b891e43e8b07dac\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30276, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61d2b1df01d7d28b891e43e8b07dac\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30276, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61d2b1eb7933e4436206410b92d6c5\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61d482e461472481ed634d8a8f2956\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30277, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 9900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 9900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 1000, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61d482e461472481ed634d8a8f2956\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30277, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61d482edd0cf7bb85b6244a4828989\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61dfff187539c74c4acb48b3b892fc\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30278, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 500, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61dfff187539c74c4acb48b3b892fc\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30278, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61dfff229f1528d960e547a6b4bad1\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61e67f9409af2f013dad4d70a3253a\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30279, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61e67f9409af2f013dad4d70a3253a\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30279, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61e67f9f8a23034044f6447e932ab3\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6208cf8ad6f761af5635490ba4bf22\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30280, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d6208cf8ad6f761af5635490ba4bf22\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30280, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d6208cfa6225a332bd9604de58416c2\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d620e937e4604c089e1064e218c4de9\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30281, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 500, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d620e937e4604c089e1064e218c4de9\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30281, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d620e9389cf5050a899504caa92ba13\\"}]}\\n"]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you are using to get the JSON data.

Comment: The fragment pasted in looks like an array with a single string element: it starts with [" and ends with "]. Is that expected?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid JSON. For example, the array/list should be delimited with commas, but I see elements that look like `[{stuff}\n{more_stuff}...]`

Comment: This doesn't look like valid JSON. Run it through a validator: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: because this is the data structure that was serialized, a list of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got an output string in that state, but it is a list with a single string containing [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/)-formatted text.

The following extracts the individual JSON lines from the existing string:

```
import json

s='''["{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6016055eae4d3e3f89d243719a272f\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30264, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d6016055eae4d3e3f89d243719a272f\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30264, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d601605a7e5cc16f5531e4efdabee0c\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d604702b7b3609fad5b7b4f63bef631\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30265, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 0, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 0, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": []}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6088b7f83e1744f17f7e4d30bb76c9\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30266, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d6088b7f83e1744f17f7e4d30bb76c9\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30266, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d6088b801f1fd4b306a9f4266b3a858\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d609444b830ade0b13e7b419eb8af2e\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30267, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d609444b830ade0b13e7b419eb8af2e\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30267, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d609444f48dbdde72c9864ec99ea271\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d60b578c55ae362f6421c405ab5e542\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30268, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d60b578c55ae362f6421c405ab5e542\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30268, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d60b578e608a00d44b2a340c7b468d5\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6106d8907ebd35b49d8e4fdc8ef0e6\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30269, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 0, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 0, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": []}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6124b3097faaf9f18e1b4dc7bd7208\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30270, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 2900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d6124b3097faaf9f18e1b4dc7bd7208\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30270, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d6124b3291c90d33d6a1245e586325b\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61689633572e1962fe3d46aeb94328\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30271, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 9900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 9900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 1000, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61689633572e1962fe3d46aeb94328\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30271, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d6168963e7816da25f7a4437db1e632\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d617924f367cf778c4d734baebf25ab\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30272, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d617924f367cf778c4d734baebf25ab\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30272, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d617924fd3674899f54f04e7c9d0ab6\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61846d719a2ec1b6dbe14806a3141d\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30273, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61846d719a2ec1b6dbe14806a3141d\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30273, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61846d7aca9ba148d09f422aba4a0a\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61994886375b4f8360784dc3ac025c\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30274, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61994886375b4f8360784dc3ac025c\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30274, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d619948a056ccfa6f19ca4a019a80d3\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61b7ee74e6c50b05f20342f0a5fe12\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30275, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 500, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61b7ee74e6c50b05f20342f0a5fe12\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30275, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61b7ee7efaaa2af9f4be4458a6fc49\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61d2b1df01d7d28b891e43e8b07dac\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30276, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61d2b1df01d7d28b891e43e8b07dac\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30276, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61d2b1eb7933e4436206410b92d6c5\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61d482e461472481ed634d8a8f2956\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30277, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 9900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 9900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 1000, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61d482e461472481ed634d8a8f2956\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30277, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61d482edd0cf7bb85b6244a4828989\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61dfff187539c74c4acb48b3b892fc\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30278, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 500, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61dfff187539c74c4acb48b3b892fc\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30278, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61dfff229f1528d960e547a6b4bad1\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d61e67f9409af2f013dad4d70a3253a\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30279, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 6900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d61e67f9409af2f013dad4d70a3253a\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30279, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d61e67f9f8a23034044f6447e932ab3\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d6208cf8ad6f761af5635490ba4bf22\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30280, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 0, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d6208cf8ad6f761af5635490ba4bf22\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30280, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d6208cfa6225a332bd9604de58416c2\\"}]}\\n{\\"uuid\\": \\"1d620e937e4604c089e1064e218c4de9\\", \\"state\\": \\"paid\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30281, \\"tax_in_cents\\": 0, \\"total_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"currency\\": \\"USD\\", \\"balance_in_cents\\": 0, \\"subtotal_before_discount_in_cents\\": 10900, \\"subtotal_in_cents\\": 10400, \\"discount_in_cents\\": 500, \\"type\\": \\"legacy\\", \\"origin\\": \\"purchase\\", \\"transaction_ids\\": [{\\"invoice_uuid\\": \\"1d620e937e4604c089e1064e218c4de9\\", \\"invoice_number\\": 30281, \\"transaction_uuid\\": \\"1d620e9389cf5050a899504caa92ba13\\"}]}\\n"]'''
items = [json.loads(line) for line in json.loads(s)[0].splitlines()]

for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
{'uuid': '1d6016055eae4d3e3f89d243719a272f', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30264, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 6900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 6900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 6900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d6016055eae4d3e3f89d243719a272f', 'invoice_number': 30264, 'transaction_uuid': '1d601605a7e5cc16f5531e4efdabee0c'}]}
{'uuid': '1d604702b7b3609fad5b7b4f63bef631', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30265, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 0, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 0, 'discount_in_cents': 10900, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': []}
{'uuid': '1d6088b7f83e1744f17f7e4d30bb76c9', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30266, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 2900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 2900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 2900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d6088b7f83e1744f17f7e4d30bb76c9', 'invoice_number': 30266, 'transaction_uuid': '1d6088b801f1fd4b306a9f4266b3a858'}]}
{'uuid': '1d609444b830ade0b13e7b419eb8af2e', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30267, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 6900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 6900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 6900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d609444b830ade0b13e7b419eb8af2e', 'invoice_number': 30267, 'transaction_uuid': '1d609444f48dbdde72c9864ec99ea271'}]}
{'uuid': '1d60b578c55ae362f6421c405ab5e542', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30268, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 2900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 2900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 2900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d60b578c55ae362f6421c405ab5e542', 'invoice_number': 30268, 'transaction_uuid': '1d60b578e608a00d44b2a340c7b468d5'}]}
{'uuid': '1d6106d8907ebd35b49d8e4fdc8ef0e6', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30269, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 0, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 0, 'discount_in_cents': 10900, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': []}
{'uuid': '1d6124b3097faaf9f18e1b4dc7bd7208', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30270, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 2900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 2900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 2900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d6124b3097faaf9f18e1b4dc7bd7208', 'invoice_number': 30270, 'transaction_uuid': '1d6124b3291c90d33d6a1245e586325b'}]}
{'uuid': '1d61689633572e1962fe3d46aeb94328', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30271, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 9900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 9900, 'discount_in_cents': 1000, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d61689633572e1962fe3d46aeb94328', 'invoice_number': 30271, 'transaction_uuid': '1d6168963e7816da25f7a4437db1e632'}]}
{'uuid': '1d617924f367cf778c4d734baebf25ab', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30272, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 10900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 10900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d617924f367cf778c4d734baebf25ab', 'invoice_number': 30272, 'transaction_uuid': '1d617924fd3674899f54f04e7c9d0ab6'}]}
{'uuid': '1d61846d719a2ec1b6dbe14806a3141d', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30273, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 6900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 6900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 6900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d61846d719a2ec1b6dbe14806a3141d', 'invoice_number': 30273, 'transaction_uuid': '1d61846d7aca9ba148d09f422aba4a0a'}]}
{'uuid': '1d61994886375b4f8360784dc3ac025c', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30274, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 6900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 6900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 6900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d61994886375b4f8360784dc3ac025c', 'invoice_number': 30274, 'transaction_uuid': '1d619948a056ccfa6f19ca4a019a80d3'}]}
{'uuid': '1d61b7ee74e6c50b05f20342f0a5fe12', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30275, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 10400, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 10400, 'discount_in_cents': 500, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d61b7ee74e6c50b05f20342f0a5fe12', 'invoice_number': 30275, 'transaction_uuid': '1d61b7ee7efaaa2af9f4be4458a6fc49'}]}
{'uuid': '1d61d2b1df01d7d28b891e43e8b07dac', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30276, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 10900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 10900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d61d2b1df01d7d28b891e43e8b07dac', 'invoice_number': 30276, 'transaction_uuid': '1d61d2b1eb7933e4436206410b92d6c5'}]}
{'uuid': '1d61d482e461472481ed634d8a8f2956', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30277, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 9900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 9900, 'discount_in_cents': 1000, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d61d482e461472481ed634d8a8f2956', 'invoice_number': 30277, 'transaction_uuid': '1d61d482edd0cf7bb85b6244a4828989'}]}
{'uuid': '1d61dfff187539c74c4acb48b3b892fc', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30278, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 10400, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 10400, 'discount_in_cents': 500, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d61dfff187539c74c4acb48b3b892fc', 'invoice_number': 30278, 'transaction_uuid': '1d61dfff229f1528d960e547a6b4bad1'}]}
{'uuid': '1d61e67f9409af2f013dad4d70a3253a', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30279, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 6900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 6900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 6900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d61e67f9409af2f013dad4d70a3253a', 'invoice_number': 30279, 'transaction_uuid': '1d61e67f9f8a23034044f6447e932ab3'}]}
{'uuid': '1d6208cf8ad6f761af5635490ba4bf22', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30280, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 10900, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 10900, 'discount_in_cents': 0, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d6208cf8ad6f761af5635490ba4bf22', 'invoice_number': 30280, 'transaction_uuid': '1d6208cfa6225a332bd9604de58416c2'}]}
{'uuid': '1d620e937e4604c089e1064e218c4de9', 'state': 'paid', 'invoice_number': 30281, 'tax_in_cents': 0, 'total_in_cents': 10400, 'currency': 'USD', 'balance_in_cents': 0, 'subtotal_before_discount_in_cents': 10900, 'subtotal_in_cents': 10400, 'discount_in_cents': 500, 'type': 'legacy', 'origin': 'purchase', 'transaction_ids': [{'invoice_uuid': '1d620e937e4604c089e1064e218c4de9', 'invoice_number': 30281, 'transaction_uuid': '1d620e9389cf5050a899504caa92ba13'}]}
```